# Dynamic width divs with spacer/bumper

Tags: html, css, dashboard, alignment

Alright I've tried to accomplish this a million different ways and can't figure out a good method.

All I want to do is to create a box in my stylesheet without a defined width to use as a module container for any number of dashboard items, then have classes for width25, width33, width50, width100 to set the width of the module container to 25%, 33%, etc... for whatever the situation calls for.

[image]

Between each container, I want to have a spacer or bumper. Let's say I have three boxes in one row: 25%, 50%, 25%. In order to add a spacer, I have to actually set my width25 to 24%, and my bumper to 1%, and things get weird trying to fill 100% of the width of the parent container. Am I making sense?

Is there a better way to do this? I run into more issues when I add padding to the boxes, because that adds to the total width of the div, too. I just want something nice and clean like this:

[image]

...where each module has the same class, save for the width class. Ideally, these widths would be width25 = 25%...width50 = 50%...and not obscure widths to make up for the bumper size.

Thoughts? This is driving me mad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems to me you have about 4 options.

1. [box-sizing: border-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing)

   -This will change how width is calulated, so if you say `width: 30%` and add a 2px border, the box remains 30%, and the border is rendered inside your specified width;
2. [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc)

   -This allows you to do things like `width: calc(20% - 2px);`
3. [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/outline)

   -The outline is rendered around the element, and doesn't affect its size. This one may not suit you.
4. divs within divs

   -Set the width of the outer div to the spacing you need, then style the inner one however you like.

Comment: This is the best answer for me. I've heard of the 960 grid system before, but you both answered my question and provided some new alternatives that I'm not familiar with. Thanks!

Comment: option 1 is the way to go in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these grid systems.

http://960.gs/

http://goldengridsystem.com/

http://grids.heroku.com/

There are plenty more. These should be enough to get you started.

`example:` http://jsfiddle.net/E9zfY/

Comment: This works great, Eric. How would I do the same for height where I can have some boxes be 50% height and stacked to match the height of the containers in the same row? (check the screenshot in the original post)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use padding. That way, the module boxes keep your math a little more reasonable, but you can create your space effect.

Drawback: You will loose px width and height in the content areas themselves, but your box model math is not so bad.